# Why won't my matrix multiplier work?

Tags: java, matrix

```
public static double[][] multiplyMatrix(double[][] matrix1, double[][] matrix2) {
        // As both arrays are square and the same size, the row size represents the row size and column size for both matrices
        int dimension = matrix1.length;

        double[][] matrix3 = new double[dimension][dimension];

        for (int i = 0; i < dimension-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dimension-1; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < dimension-1; j++) {
                    matrix3[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
                }
            }
        }

        return matrix3;
    }
```

It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like k equals zero all the time. You are incrementing j in both loops.

Comment: god I hope that's not the reason it's not working on his part

Answer (score 5):

Your for loops need to go one more iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dimension-1; i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
```

Also update your `j` and `k` loops the same way (and your `k` loop increments `j`, which just looks like a copy/paste error).

Answer (score 1):

This code produces an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You are incrementing `j` in `k`'s `` `for `` loop. Better to use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < dimension; k++) {
            matrix3[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```